# Обводка и создание сложной фигуры в HTML

Tags: html, css, html5, sass

Помогите пожалуйста создать такую фигуру и обводить её так как показано на скриншоте. Заранее большое спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а сложная фигура это что из всего этого ?

Comment: Так скажем, мега меню. Обновил скриншот, посмотрите ещё раз пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ в рамках скриншота

> смотреть на полный экран

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 4px;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 145px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.elem {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-top: none;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: -1px;
}

.elem button {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  top: 52px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    <button>тарабарщина</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: deleted. спасибо большое, увидел

Comment: я же сделал уже - разве нет ??